# Tagalog language pack in Ubuntu 15.10?

Tags: 15.10, language-support

I want to know how to install the Tagalog language pack for Ubuntu 15.10.

I know it's available in [precise and trusty](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=language-pack-tl), but I can't seem to install it in willy.

Here's what I've done so far:

```
janreggie@janreggie-T100TA:~$ sudo apt-get install language-pack-tl
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package language-pack-tl
janreggie@janreggie-T100TA:~$ sudo apt-get install language-pack-tl-base
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package language-pack-tl-base
```

I also tried installing `language-pack-fil`.

```
janreggie@janreggie-T100TA:~$ sudo apt-get install language-pack-fil
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package language-pack-fil
```

Does anyone know how to install the proper repositories?

Salamat!

Answer (score 0):

Right, it's [not available after Trusty](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/language-pack-tl), and I would guess the reason is that there are so [few translations](https://translations.launchpad.net/ubuntu/xenial/+lang/tl).

Comment: It's quite a shame that there are only a few translations.

Thanks man.